How does Compton Scattering prove particle nature of electromagnetic radiation?
In Compton effect, just a photon playing pool, hitting an electron and bouncing off.
But in Arthur Compton article,
this effect demonstrated the particle nature of electromagnetic radiation.
How does Compton Scattering prove particle nature of electromagnetic radiation?

Also Which particle aspect is required to explain photoelectric or Compton effect?

And Why does compton scattering provide evidence for the particle nature of light?
